# Python xgboost on Windows machine

Tags: python, xgboost

I am succeeded to install xgboost on windows machine and `import xgboost` inside the Spyder is working , but when I try to run xgboost.train I get the following error :

> ```
> File "C:\Users\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\xgboost-0.4-py2.7.egg\xgboost\core.py", 
> line 806, in update _check_call(_LIB.XGBoosterUpdateOneIter(self.handle, iteration, dtrain.handle))
> WindowsError: [Error 541541187] Windows Error 0x20474343
> ```

Any ideas how to solve it ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that's an error coming from the c++ implementation nothing to do with your python installation. Try to install a previous or later version.